# How can I avoid big images from flashing when entering the website again?

Tags: javascript, image, firefox, browser

If you have a website with a really big image as the background, the image flashes for a split second whenever you enter the site again after you have left it and you visit other sites in other tabs. It feels like the browser is reloading the image.

It does not happen if you enter the site immediately after you have left the site, it takes maybe 30 seconds.

Can this problem be fixed programmatically, or is it browser related?

PS. I use firefox, it does not happen in Chrome or IE.

PS. The size of the image is 423 kb.

Comment: how are you setting up the background image? the CSS3 way (background-image, background-size:cover) or the old school way (<img> tag, blown up to the screen)?

Comment: Like this: 
background: url('img.jpg') no-repeat;
background-size: cover;

Comment: Which headers are sent with the image file?

Comment: GET /img/img.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://www.example.com/css/css.css
Connection: keep-alive
If-Modified-Since: Wed, 23 Jan 2013 20:14:43 GMT
If-None-Match: "50647e2-69ca1-4d3fa584cb00e"
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Wed, 30 Jan 2013 19:20:04 GMT
Server: Apache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=93
Etag: "50647e2-69ca1-4d3fa584cb00e"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding placement information, as well as fallback color information:

```
background:#ccc url('img.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
```

Firefox usually likes things to be more explicitly coded (position:absolute, for example).